# Add a tolerance to a gap with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Edit 1: Printed the output from the sample code.

Using pandas to find gaps in a set of syslog files. Example below gives me a True/False value for where the values of `real_date` are further apart than the 120 seconds I want to tolerate (lines 4029,30)

I've found that a significant number of entries in syslog can have a slight inaccuracy in the timestamp (lines 4027, 4028). I'm guessing that because line 4028 is an earlier value than line 4027 the comparison correctly ends up being true.

How could I make it tolerate a difference of say 1 second?

```
import pandas as pd
import io

maximum_tolerated_gap_in_seconds = 120
gaps_to_ignore = 1
seconds_per_day = 86400

df[column_name] = pd.to_datetime(df[column_name], errors='coerce')
df.dropna(inplace=True, subset=[column_name])

df['time_difference'] = df[column_name].diff().dt.seconds
df['test_gap'] = (df[column_name].diff().dt.seconds) <= maximum_tolerated_gap_in_seconds
test_data = """"line_number","line_length","syslog_date","unix_timestamp","real_date"
4026,110,"Jul 19 01:00:01",1626656401.0,"2021-07-19T01:00:01"
4027,97,"Jul 19 01:00:02",1626656402.0,"2021-07-19T01:00:02"
4028,110,"Jul 19 01:00:01",1626656401.0,"2021-07-19T01:00:01"
4029,110,"Jul 19 01:00:01",1626656401.0,"2021-07-19T01:00:01"
4030,110,"Jul 19 01:00:01",1626656401.0,"2021-07-19T01:30:00"
"""

test_data_file = io.StringIO(test_data)
df = pd.read_csv(test_data_file)

column_name = "real_date"
df.head()
```

Output:

```
line_number line_length syslog_date unix_timestamp  real_date   time_difference test_gap
0   4026    110 Jul 19 01:00:01 1.626656e+09    2021-07-19 01:00:01 NaN False
1   4027    97  Jul 19 01:00:02 1.626656e+09    2021-07-19 01:00:02 1.0 True
2   4028    110 Jul 19 01:00:01 1.626656e+09    2021-07-19 01:00:01 86399.0 False
3   4029    110 Jul 19 01:00:01 1.626656e+09    2021-07-19 01:00:01 0.0 True
4   4030    110 Jul 19 01:00:01 1.626656e+09    2021-07-19 01:30:00 1799.0  False
```

So when the timestamps for line 4027 is out 1 second ahead of the next line 4028 the comparison value is 86399.0 which is greater than `max_tolerated_gap_in_seconds`.

I guess: How do I ignore that when it's only 1 second but shows up as 86399 seconds because of the out of order time?

Edit 2:

This is the code updated with `adr` suggested change to use `dt.total_seconds()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

maximum_tolerated_gap_in_seconds = 120
gaps_to_ignore = 1
seconds_per_day = 86400

test_data = """"line_number","line_length","syslog_date","unix_timestamp","real_date"
4026,110,"Jul 19 01:00:01",1626656401.0,"2021-07-19T01:00:01"
4027,97,"Jul 19 01:00:02",1626656402.0,"2021-07-19T01:00:02"
4028,110,"Jul 19 01:00:01",1626656401.0,"2021-07-19T01:00:01"
4029,110,"Jul 19 01:00:01",1626656401.0,"2021-07-19T01:00:01"
4030,110,"Jul 19 01:00:01",1626656401.0,"2021-07-19T01:30:00"
"""

test_data_file = io.StringIO(test_data)
df = pd.read_csv(test_data_file)
column_name = "real_date"

df[column_name] = pd.to_datetime(df[column_name], errors='coerce')
df.dropna(inplace=True, subset=[column_name])

df['time_difference'] = df[column_name].diff().dt.total_seconds()
df['test_gap'] = (df[column_name].diff().dt.total_seconds()) <= maximum_tolerated_gap_in_seconds

print(df.head())
```

and the output:

```
$ python sample.py
   line_number  line_length      syslog_date  unix_timestamp           real_date  time_difference  test_gap
0         4026          110  Jul 19 01:00:01    1.626656e+09 2021-07-19 01:00:01              NaN     False
1         4027           97  Jul 19 01:00:02    1.626656e+09 2021-07-19 01:00:02              1.0      True
2         4028          110  Jul 19 01:00:01    1.626656e+09 2021-07-19 01:00:01             -1.0      True
3         4029          110  Jul 19 01:00:01    1.626656e+09 2021-07-19 01:00:01              0.0      True
4         4030          110  Jul 19 01:00:01    1.626656e+09 2021-07-19 01:30:00           1799.0     False
```

That works nicely.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Edited to show output from sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accessor `dt.seconds` always gives you a positive time value.  The days will go negative to make this happen.  Try `dt.total_seconds()` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much. That's working really nicely for me.